# Passing of changed variables only in C++

Tags: c++

I need some help to make my code more efficient. The codelines do what I want , but it is
poorly done. I need it to be more efficient as I later will increase the amount of data and then the functions will be too slow.

I'm a newcomer too C++ and programming, so any suggestion are welcomed so I can learn more.

AS there are very few changes most of the time I just want the changed values in function A to be sent further by the function B. Now in my codes every values are sent further on even when not changes at all. This is waste of resources and not good programming, I know.

Important!
1)The values of the first parameter of IOCP.sendVarData are static and can not be changed.
2) The PmdgGetVariable ("MCP_annunFD", &result) in function B initiate everything.
What would be the best way to improve this this?

I have the function below that detects any changes from last time it was runned and store the changes.

// This function is called when NGX data changes
void ProcessNGXData (PMDG_NGX_Data *pS)
{

```
if (pS->MCP_Course[0]   != NGX_MCP_Course[0]){NGX_MCP_Course[0] = pS->MCP_Course[0];}
if (pS->MCP_Course[1]   != NGX_MCP_Course[1]){NGX_MCP_Course[1] = pS->MCP_Course[1];}
if (pS->MCP_IASMach     != NGX_MCP_IASMach){NGX_MCP_IASMach     = pS->MCP_IASMach;}
if (pS->MCP_Heading     != NGX_MCP_Heading){NGX_MCP_Heading     = pS->MCP_Heading;} 
if (pS->MCP_Altitude    != NGX_MCP_Altitude){NGX_MCP_Altitude   = pS->MCP_Altitude;}
if (pS->MCP_VertSpeed   != NGX_MCP_VertSpeed){NGX_MCP_VertSpeed = pS->MCP_VertSpeed;}

if (pS->MCP_annunLVL_CHG != NGX_MCP_annunLVL_CHG){NGX_MCP_annunLVL_CHG = pS->MCP_annunLVL_CHG;}


if (pS->MCP_annunN1         != NGX_MCP_annunN1)     {NGX_MCP_annunN1 =      pS->MCP_annunN1;}
if (pS->MCP_annunSPEED      != NGX_MCP_annunSPEED)  {NGX_MCP_annunSPEED =   pS->MCP_annunSPEED;}
if (pS->MCP_annunVNAV       != NGX_MCP_annunVNAV)   {NGX_MCP_annunVNAV =    pS->MCP_annunVNAV;}
if (pS->MCP_annunLVL_CHG    != NGX_MCP_annunLVL_CHG){NGX_MCP_annunLVL_CHG = pS->MCP_annunLVL_CHG;}
if (pS->MCP_annunHDG_SEL    != NGX_MCP_annunHDG_SEL){NGX_MCP_annunHDG_SEL = pS->MCP_annunHDG_SEL;}
if (pS->MCP_annunLNAV       != NGX_MCP_annunLNAV)   {NGX_MCP_annunLNAV =    pS->MCP_annunLNAV;}
if (pS->MCP_annunVOR_LOC    != NGX_MCP_annunVOR_LOC){NGX_MCP_annunVOR_LOC = pS->MCP_annunVOR_LOC ;}
if (pS->MCP_annunAPP        != NGX_MCP_annunAPP )   {NGX_MCP_annunAPP  =    pS->MCP_annunAPP ;}
if (pS->MCP_annunALT_HOLD   != NGX_MCP_annunALT_HOLD){NGX_MCP_annunALT_HOLD = pS->MCP_annunALT_HOLD ;}
if (pS->MCP_annunVS         != NGX_MCP_annunVS )    {NGX_MCP_annunVS  =      pS->MCP_annunVS ;}
if (pS->MCP_annunCMD_A      != NGX_MCP_annunCMD_A ) {NGX_MCP_annunCMD_A  =  pS->MCP_annunCMD_A ;}
if (pS->MCP_annunCWS_A      != NGX_MCP_annunCWS_A ) {NGX_MCP_annunCWS_A  =  pS->MCP_annunCWS_A ;}
if (pS->MCP_annunCMD_B      != NGX_MCP_annunCMD_B ) {NGX_MCP_annunCMD_B  =  pS->MCP_annunCMD_B ;}
if (pS->MCP_annunCWS_B      != NGX_MCP_annunCWS_B)  {NGX_MCP_annunCWS_B  =  pS->MCP_annunCWS_B ;}
}
```

In another thread I now have this function to send the

```
static UINT running_as_Thread(LPVOID lpvoid) {
            int  result;
            bool rep= true;
            while (rep){
            PmdgGetVariable ("MCP_annunFD", &result);       
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 2534, NGX_MCP_Course [0]);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 2524,  NGX_MCP_Altitude);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 2542, NGX_MCP_Heading);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 2559, NGX_MCP_IASMach);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 1140, NGX_MCP_VertSpeed);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 2535, NGX_MCP_Course [1]);   
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 286, NGX_MCP_annunLVL_CHG);  
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 1143, NGX_MCP_VertSpeedBlank);   
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 1115, NGX_MCP_IASBlank); 
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 1117 , NGX_MCP_IASOverspeedFlash);       
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 1118, NGX_MCP_IASUnderspeedFlash);           
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 282, NGX_MCP_annunATArm);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 283, NGX_MCP_annunN1);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 284, NGX_MCP_annunSPEED);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 285, NGX_MCP_annunVNAV);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 286, NGX_MCP_annunLVL_CHG);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 287, NGX_MCP_annunHDG_SEL);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 288, NGX_MCP_annunLNAV);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 289, NGX_MCP_annunVOR_LOC);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 290, NGX_MCP_annunAPP);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 291, NGX_MCP_annunALT_HOLD);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 292, NGX_MCP_annunVS);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 293, NGX_MCP_annunCMD_A);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 294, NGX_MCP_annunCWS_A);
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 295, NGX_MCP_annunCMD_B);    
            IOCP.sendVarData ( 296, NGX_MCP_annunCWS_B);
Sleep (400);
}
    return THREAD_EXIT_OK;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion No 1: If the type of "pS->MCP_annun*"s is a basic one, drop the ifs before the assignment

Answer (score 0):

A few things first:

Nobody wants to know you have both a `NGX_MCP_annunCMD_A` and a `NGX_MCP_annunCMD_B`. We are interested in a small sample of code that illustrates the problem, preferably with as little domain-specific information as possible. If it actually compiles, that's super.

Two things you didn't mention, but should have:

1. Are all the members of `PMDG_NGX_Data` [PODs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) (int, float, structures holding int, float...)?
2. Since you mention threads, are all the members of `PMDG_NGX_Data` independent, or do you need a locking mechanism?

Regarding your first function, `ProcessNGXData` :

If all the members of `PMDG_NGX_Data` are PODs and it processes all the members of the struct then it is equivalent with the shorter and maybe faster:

```
PMDG_NGX_Data NGX_MCP_bakup;
void ProcessNGXData (PMDG_NGX_Data *pS) 
{
    NGX_MCP_bakup = *pS;
}
```

As a solution to your original problem, you could try this:

- create a wrapper class over the basic `PMDG_NGX_Data`, this will be responsible for tracking the changes.
- this wrapper exposes the fields of the underlying structure via getters and setters.
- the setters detect if the value being set is different from the current and, if it is, change the value and add it to a list of changes (a list of pairs of the ID  and the new value).
- the wrapper class also has a method which accepts a `IOCP` object, calls `sendVarData` for each ID and value in the list of changes and clears the change list.

Make sure you add the necessary locking and handle the case where the same parameter is changed multiple times between calls to the "send changes function"

As with all optimizations: "Are you sure it is necessary?" and "Make sure to test and see it actually works better."